# Want to create a scheduled firestore script. Need pointers

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Creating an App with Firestore. Need cloud function for document matches that creates new documents/records at periodic intervals.

Looked at firestore cloud functions but still not clear.

My existing knowledge: Create SQL Command bash script as a cron job.

I installed Firebase CLI, setup functions, created example but still unsure what documentation to read nor have good examples to manipulate firestore on a schedule.

Should I use realmDB instead?

App has chat component & data matching creates new records/documents every 6 hours.

Potentially creates upwards of 100,000 records/documents at a time - periodically purged after 14 days.

Comment: Just found this so will see if this is helpful: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/uppercase-firestore

Comment: Follow this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) to run CF on a schedule.

Comment: You can create a cloud functions on firebase, and then get a third party service to call that cloud function, such as https://cron-job.org/en/

Firebase has some good documentation on how to make a http request to execute a cloud function: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to use Firebase Cloud Functions to trigger at periodic intervals (similar to Cron jobs) and run some code, you can use this handy convenience method by Firebase Cloud Functions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions.

```
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('5 11 * * *')
  .timeZone('Asia/Kolkata') 
  .onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every day at 11:00 AM IST!');
  return null;
});
```

You can also setup Google Cloud Pub-Sub triggers manually and use Cloud Scheduler (a Cron job scheduler for GCP) to trigger Pub-Sub trigger.

Comment: I want to run a function on 1-minute interval when any record created. Is that possible with it?